# My Token wont send from My Ether wallet- keeps saying pending

Tags: myetherwallet

Myetherwallet Keeps saying pending and nothing will transfer?
tx Hash: 0xa01498ed5b18cdfa4795261f49c06f279ddbfb6bac8a5335e11ba70ec61ffd39

What should I do? Thanks in advance

Comment: same problem. keeps failing... this is sad for eth... always failed transaction.

Answer (score 1):

Your gas price is a bit low. (https://www.ethgasstation.info/ recommends a "safe low" price of 32 gwei, but you used 21 gwei.)

I would recommend just waiting. It might take a couple hours.

Comment: It didn't go through at all, what should I do?

Comment: You can cancel it here: https://www.myetherwallet.com/#check-tx-status and then just try again (using a higher gas price).